# how to stop recursion after printing 5 terms in this Fibonacci series code?

Tags: java, recursion

```
class FibR
{
   int c=0;
   void fib(int i,int j,int n){
     if(c==n) return;
     System.out.print(i+" "+j+" ");
     int t=j;
     i=i+j;
     j=i+t;
     c++;
     fib(i,j,n);     
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       FibR f=new FibR();
       f.fib(0,1,5);
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34
```

I need to print only `0 1 1 2 3 ,i.e`, 5 terms 
What corrections do I need to the condition in if statement ? Tried `c+=2` instead of `c++` ,but the code enters into infinite loop.
Thanks in advance

Comment: reduce your counter to 3 insted of 5 and note that you are printing in pairs, so... your output will be 0 1 1 2 3 5

Comment: Actually you can do **c+=2**, and change the if to **if(c>=n)** . You are printing two values at time, so those two values get printed 5*2 times based on your current code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to use `c += 2` you should also include equality in your `if-statement`.

```
class FibR
{
   int c = 0 ;
   void fib(int i, int j, int n){
     if (c >= n) return;
     System.out.print(i+" " + j +" ");
     int t = j;
     i += j;
     j = i + t;
     c += 2;
     fib(i, j, n);     
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       FibR f = new FibR();
       f.fib(0, 1, 5);
       System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Since you can't get just 5 characters, the output will be:

```
0 1 1 2 3 5
```

Answer (score 6):

In each of your `fib` call, you print two fib numbers:`System.out.print(i+" "+j+" ");`

Following is a simplier version:

```
public class FibR {
void fib(int i, int j, int n) {
    if (n == 0) return;
    System.out.println(i);
    fib(j, i + j, n - 1);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    FibR f = new FibR();
    f.fib(0, 1, 5);
}
}
```

Each time you call `fib`, you pass the latest two number (`i` and `j`), and how many number left to print (`n`).

Answer (score 3):

As you are printing both `i` and `j` together, you can't print 5 terms. It can be either 4 or 6.

Now, as far as infinite loop is concerned, if you are changing `c++` to `c+=2` then you need to change `if (c == n)` to `if (c >= n)` as `c` will be greater than 5 after 2nd iteration.

Answer (score 2):

Reduce the counter to 3 and if your iteration reaches counter -1 just print i and drop j

```
class FibR {
    int c = 0;

    void fib(int i, int j, int n) {
        if (c == n) return;
        if (c < n - 1)
            System.out.print(i + " " + j + " ");
        else
            System.out.print(i);//c == n-1 => just print i

        int t = j;i = i + j;j = i + t;c++;fib(i, j, n);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FibR f = new FibR();
        f.fib(0, 1, 3);//reduce to 3
    }
}
```

Comment: By changing code from **int c = 0** to **static int c = 0**, you are going to put the guy in some real trouble when he will start things like , **FibR f = new FibR() , other = new FibR(); f.fib(0,1,3); other.fib(0,1,3)**. The guy would be crying :)

Comment: Yes u're right! Don't know why i did this. Updated the code. Thanks!

Comment: No problem at all :)

Answer (score 0):

Why would you write your function like that? Since it is recursion, your function should only take one parameter, the number of elements you want.

It seems you over complicated it using 3 arguments.

Answer (score 0):

In a recursive function, you'd better not save/depends on some external status/fileds. And in your example code, it's because you print two terms in each call, so you'll never make it print odd numbers.

Comment: if you can describe your answer using code, that will be helpful